# Polish space of measurable functions

Tags: metric-spaces, measurable-functions

Is it possible to extend the set of measurable functions $F := \{ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \mid f \text{ is Lebesgue measurable }\}$ to a Polish space?

I feel like the biggest obstacle is to find a metric on $F$ such that $F$ has a dense subset.

(Note that I do not want to restrict $F$ to continuous functions only.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many measurable functions for this to work: if we let $A$ be a measure-zero set, then the characteristic function of $A$ is measurable, but there are more than continuum many measure-zero sets - and every Polish space has size at most continuum.

Comment: @Peter I interpreted "measurable function" as taking the measurable sets on the domain, and the Borel sets on the codomain; that is, $f$ is measurable if the preimage of every Borel set is Lebesgue measurable. I believe this is the standard definition. If you use the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in both cases, then my answer does not work of course, but you should state that explicitly in your question.